# Differentiable at $x=0$ only

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

Let

$f(x) = x^2*1$ if $x$ is rational

$f(x) = x^2*0$ if $x$ is irrational

Show that $f$ is diﬀerentiable at 0 and not diﬀerentiable elsewhere.

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you familiar with the nowhere diﬀerentiable Drichlet function? That proof could help you a lot.

Comment: I haven't been taught it. I have attempted using the definition of differentiable at a (the limit as h->0 of 1/h(f(a+h)-f(a)), but I haven't had any joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is clearly not even continuous away from $0,$ so it can't be differentiable there.

At $0$ we have

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^2}{h} = 0$$

(this is when $h$ takes rational values, and it's constantly $0$ when $h$ takes irrational values anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta = \epsilon$:
$$|x|=|x-0|< \delta \implies |\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} - 0|=|\frac{f(x)}{x}| \leq |\frac{x^2}{x}|=|x| < \delta = \epsilon$$
So $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

If $x_0 \neq 0$ is rational, and $\epsilon =x_0^2$, then for every $\delta >0$ there will be an  irrational $x$ satisfying $|x_0 - x| < \delta$ and $|f(x_0) - f(x)|=|f(x_0) - 0|=x_0^2 \geq \epsilon$.

So $f$ is not continuous at  every rational $x \neq 0$, and hence not differentiable.

If necessary use the same reasoning to show that $f$ is not continuous at irational $x$'s..